# how to skip one row in getView() which shown in listview

Tags: android

For example, I would like to display the name, gender and age in the listview.
And for age under 18, I want to skip the row. Is there any solution to do this?
One of the answer is that I should edit the sql that in the server side.
However, if I cannot handle/touch the server side, can I do it in client side?
I am new to Android, please help me...

Comment: Or you could edit the SQL query that goes to the server from the app...

Comment: assuming that I cannot do anything in server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As esse said You may have to ignore the particular row.
Its not just creating the row but also skipping the rows which we don't need.

Comment: even I set convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE), not ok

Comment: are you getting a blank list item?

Comment: yes, it is so strange, a really blank list item between the listview

Comment: I think you are inflating and returning the view outside the  condition (age<18).

Comment: Or else try another way
display all the items and later check for those values which has age < 18 and delete them from the listview and use notifydatasetchanged()

Comment: but how to delete list items?

Comment: how are you trying to set the list view?
I are you using any arraylist of the items or any other?

Comment: then before setting adapter traverse through the arraylist and check for the particular list item (age < 18) and delete it from the arraylist and later call the setListAdapter(......).

Comment: You idea is very great!! I never think in this way!!

Comment: sorry i don't know whether its really useful to you or not.
Or better i could try to help a little bit more if you provide few more details

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are downloading the data as text from the server? If this is correct you can simply set up a condition to ignore the rows where age < 18. You would do this in your ListView Adapter.

You may want to give more details, explain your question better, to get a better answer.

Comment: how to skip a row or not create a row in getView()